# Find the inverse of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the inverse of the matrix

```
B=    1 0 2
      0 -1 1
      1 1 0

Thats easy -1  2  2
            1 -2 -1
            1 -1 -1
```

But how do i show this

```
Hence solve BX = -3   where X = x1
                  4             x2
                  5             x3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$
C = \begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\
4 \\
5
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now,
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
BX&=&C\\
B^{-1}BX &=& B^{-1}C\\
X = B^{-1}C &=& \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & -2 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & -1
\end{bmatrix} \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\
4 \\
5
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
3+8+10 \\
-3-8-5\\
-3-4-5
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
21 \\
-16 \\
-12
\end{bmatrix}\\
X=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix} &=& \begin{bmatrix}
21 \\
-16 \\
-12
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $v$ be the given vector (that is, the column vector $(-3,4,5)$). You have the equation $BX=v$. Multiplying on both sides by $B^{-1}$ gives $B^{-1}BX=B^{-1}v$, or $X=B^{-1}v$. You can easily compute the right hand side to find $X$.